# iOS GPS Distance Calculations between 2 locations

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, haversine

I created an app that shows the distance between 2 iOS devices. I got 
the coordinates  using GPSKit and computes the distance using ZFHaversine. Both of them are libraries from cocoapods.org.

Now my problem is even if the device are placed side by side, the distance registered is +/- 70 meters. I am trying to find a way to make the computed distance, at least into +/- 5 meters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update, for now I have used the Equirectangular Approximation formula on the ZFHaversine pod. This is more accurate on shorter distances.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use CoreBluetooth in this situation. AFAIK CoreBluetooth can measure signal strength, so that you would be able to calculate distance more precisely.

Comment: Thanks of the suggestion but core bluetooth but I think core bluetooth is limited to the rssi signal strength. Therefor can only give me Far, Intermediate and Near

Answer (score 0):

Import Core Location Framework. Get coordinates in form of CLLocation

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude1 longitude:longitude1];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude2 longitude:longitude2];
```

Now get the distance

```
CGFloat distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was using this before havesine. Haversine gives me better figures.